# Why do we need isomorphism between a diagram and a cone L for it to be a limit?

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I read from [these slides](http://fsl.cs.illinois.edu/images/a/a8/CS522-Fall-2018-Category-Theory-slides.pdf):

> a limit of a diagram containing just one object A and no
>   morphism is any object L that is isomorphic to A (the
>   isomorphism is part of the limit);

and was unsure why we needed the isomorphism between $A$ and $L$. Isn't $L$ in this scenario a limit **even if A and L are not isomorphic** because **there is no other cone** (so that condition is vacuously satisfied?).

i.e. if L points to diagram A, isn't L a limit of that diagram?

---

**How does the isomorphism play a role in showing that $L$ is a limit of the diagram $A$**?

---

My thoughts:

The way I understand the question is as follows. The claim is that a limit of a diagram with a single object $A$ is any $(L,\delta_A)$ such that $L \cong A$. So if $L \cong A$ then it is a limit. To show $L$ is a limit we need to show that

1. $(L,\delta_A)$ is a conde of the diagram $d$ (which is trivial)
2. for any other cone $(C,\gamma_A)$ that there exists a unique factorization given by $\gamma_A = h; \delta_A$.

In particular I believe there are two cases to check:

1. $C = A$
2. $C \neq A$

I think for case 1 part of the proof goes as follow: Consider any cone $(C,\gamma_A)$. Then for $(L,\delta_A)$ to be a limit we need to check $\gamma_A = h; \delta_A = \delta \circ h$ (assume we already know they are cones of $d$). Since we know $L \cong A$ we know there exists $f: L \to A$ and $g: A \to L$ such that $f;g = 1_L$ and $g;f = 1_A$. Therefore to satisfy $\gamma_A = h; \delta_A$ choose the $h$ that makes $1_A= h; \delta_A$ true. Here is where I get confused:

1. How do I know $\gamma_A = 1_A$? Is this where the assumption in the paragraph I quoted goes into play? i.e. "the isomorphism is part of the limit". How do we know $\delta_A$ does have that property? $\delta_A$ is a morphism from $L \to A$. If this was in the category Set it could be that $\delta_A$ maps everything from $L$ to a single element of $A$, which makes it non-invertible, so I can't see how the bijection could take place.

the second case is even less clear to me how we show such a factorization exists and what is the role of saying $L$ is isomorphic to $A$ is.

Comment: Why do you say there is no other cone?  You seem to not understand the definition of a cone.

Comment: @EricWofsey that could be true! My understanding of a cone of a diagram d is a pair $(C,\{ \gamma_i\}_{i \in V})$ such that these triangles commute with the help of an edge in the diagram i.e. $\gamma_i ; d(i \to j) = \gamma_j$ where $\gamma_j = C \to d(j)$ is a morphism from the object $C$ to the object in the diagram $d(j)$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I say there is no other cone because $L$ is the only thing "pointing" to the diagram where $A$ lives.

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought the only cone in question was the one related to $L$. Did I misunderstand that paragraph?

Comment: Why would $L$ be the only thing "pointing" to the diagram?

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I just don't understand the english of the scenario in question "a limit of a diagram containing just one object A and no morphism is any object L that is isomorphic to A (the isomorphism is part of the limit);". I don't think there are any other cones because no other cones are mentioned? Why would I assume random things exist for this diagram out of the blue? Is that unreasonable? Or did I miss something crucial in the definitions?

Comment: Well, you don't _know_ that other things exist, but you can't assume they _don't_ exist either.  If you write the equation $2+2=4$ that is not denying the existence of any numbers besides $2$ and $4$...

Comment: @EricWofsey sure but how do I know we are not in a scenario where no other cone exists? There could be a scenario like that with a specific diagram and Category where that happens (just assume one by definition). Then there are no other cones and the isomorphic conditions would be redundant. Is at least this correct?

Comment: Well, there might be no other cones.  But as I said in my answer, that still doesn't make the definition vacuous, since the definition still has to hold for the one cone that does exist.

Comment: (Since the identity map $1_A:A\to A$ is always a cone, if there are no other cones then the unique cone must be the identity map, which is an isomorphism and therefore a limit.  But the fact that it is a limit does not at all follow immediately just from it being the only cone.)

Comment: @EricWofsey I think I am confused what "any other" means. For me it means consider the set of cones **different** from L (what I thought the word "other" meant, otherwise it should just say "any"). So the set Cones\L.

Comment: In the definition of a limit, "any other" means just "any".  This is quite common in math, though you will also sometimes find "any other" used to mean "any different from the one we have".  The latter usage is somewhat informal and should not be used unless it is completely clear what is meant from context.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of cones!  For any object $B$, every morphism $f:B\to A$ is a cone over this diagram.  So the condition for $i:L \to A$ to be a limit is that for every $f:B\to A$ there exists a unique $g:B\to L$ such that $ig=f$.  Taking $B=A$ and $f=1_A$ gives a morphism $g$ such that $ig=1_A$.  We then have $igi=i=i1_L$ which implies $gi=1_L$ using the uniqueness condition with $f=i$.  So, $i$ is an isomorphism with inverse $g$.

I would also remark that even if there are no *other* cones, that still doesn't immediately imply that $i:L\to A$ is a limit, since $i:L\to A$ is still a cone and so the definition is not vacuous.  The limit condition is required to hold for *all* cones, not just those that are different from the limiting cone.

Comment: how do you know $ig = 1_A$ is true?

Comment: That's by definition of $g$: it's the unique $g$ such that $ig=f$, for $f=1_A$.

Comment: I see I guess that the part that **needs** the isomorphism between A and L. i.e. without that $g$ wouldn't exist. i.e. we choose the "other" cone $B$ to be $A$ isomorphic to $L$. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The argument I gave is a _proof_ that $i:A\to L$ is an isomorphism, assuming it is a limit.  So, that argument is the reason why you must have an isomorphism.

Comment: you know what " (the isomorphism is part of the limit)" means?

Comment: It means that the isomorphism is the map to $A$ in the limiting cone.

Comment: why are you saying "i to be a limit". I thought that the limit is the cone with a the usual universal property. What I am confused is what morphisms are present in the cone $(L,\{ \delta_A \}_{A \in d} )$ What are the members of the morphism to the diagram that are part of the cone? Making that explicit would help me.

Comment: $i=\delta_A$ in this case.  There is only one object in the diagram (namely $A$), and $i$ is the map from $L$ to it.

Comment: The key thing is for me to understand why the isomorphism condition is needed. Since $(L,i)$ is a limit it has to factorize with any other cone via $f = i \circ g$ with a unique $g$ (the universal property). Since this has to hold for every other cone it has to also hold for the cone $B = A$ too and that case only factorizes as we want if $f = 1_A$. Thats why we need the isomorphism. Otherwise there is no reason for $ig$ to be equal to $f$ (which points to itself). Is that correct?

Comment: There is no one-line reason that we "need the isomorphism".  A proof of why $i$ must be an isomorphism if $(L,i)$ is a limit is the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Sure, there needs to be a map $g$ such that $ig=1_A$.  That alone doesn't mean that $i$ is an isomorphism though; you still have to also prove that $gi=1_L$.

Comment: If L wasn't isomorphic to L then there would be one cone that doesn't factorize as we need, so there is one line proof that $(L,i)$ wouldn't be a cone without that key property of object $L$. No?

Comment: You're jumping to all sorts of unwarranted conclusions.  Why couldn't the cone with $f=1_A$ factorize if $i$ was not an isomorphism?  Just because you can't think of a reason that it would factorize doesn't mean that it's not possible.

Comment: This is a tendency I've noticed in your thought patterns over and over.  You assume that just because you don't see a reason for something to be true, it must be false.  This is a really really bad habit that you should break out of.  You can't conclude that something doesn't exist unless you can _prove_ it doesn't exist.  It's not enough to just not have a reason that it must exist.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. If they are isomorphic then they do factorize **for sure** is I guess the point. I'm jumping to conclusions probably because I'm new to CT and because by default I don't hold believes unless they are shown true. My default stance is something is false until proven true (in general). Perhaps I should hold a more agnostic default.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I appreciate it. Habits are hard to break out of if I am not aware of them. Now that you've kindly pointed it out I will try to empower myself with it :) . Also, note that "You can't conclude that something doesn't exist unless you can prove it doesn't exist." is a ridiculous thing to believe in the real world. I am a scientist that interacts with the real world. It's usually intractable to show the none-existence of things in the real world. I guess not so in maths and thats where I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: sorry for dragging this longer, but I am immensely grateful with your patience and feedback. In the case where $A \neq B$ and $(B,\gamma_A)$ is a cone of the diagram $d$, how do we show $\gamma_A$ has a unique factorization $ \gamma_A= h ; \delta_A = \delta_A \circ h$ where $(L,\delta_A)$ is the limiting cone of $d$ (with the isomorphic property in the original question.

Comment: The factorization you want is $\gamma_A=\delta_A g$ for some unique $g$.  Just note that $\gamma_A=\delta_A g$ is equivalent to $\delta_A^{-1}\gamma_A=g$ so $\delta_A^{-1}\gamma_A$ is the unique $g$.